# How to resolve openssl not found error while installing new Python version with Pyenv on M1 Mac OS Ventura 13.1?

Tags: python, macos, terminal, openssl, apple-m1

The system is M1 processor on MacOS Ventura 13.1. While installing a new version with `pyenv`, it throws following error regarding `openssl` not found on the system. `openssl` is already installed with the version number `LibreSSL 3.3.6`

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'readline'
WARNING: The Python readline extension was not compiled. Missing the GNU readline lib?
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/Users/divyesh.parmar@postman.com/.pyenv/versions/3.10.6/lib/python3.10/ssl.py", line 99, in <module>
    import _ssl             # if we can't import it, let the error propagate
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '_ssl'
ERROR: The Python ssl extension was not compiled. Missing the OpenSSL lib?
```

I've mostly tried approaches mentioned on this thread, but none of that seems to lead to anywhere. How to resolve this?

Answer (score 1):

After looking at several Github threads on `Pyenv` project, one of the simplest method worked like a charm.

```
# Providing an incorrect openssl version forces a proper openssl version to be downloaded and linked during the build
export PYTHON_BUILD_HOMEBREW_OPENSSL_FORMULA=openssl@1.0
```

After setting this, upon running the command to install any version, it will automatically download and link the required version of `openssl`

Reference : https://github.com/pyenv/pyenv/issues/1768#issuecomment-1423144852

Answer (score 0):

You can use a higher version of openssl with :

```
export CONFIGURE_OPTS="--with-openssl=$(brew --prefix openssl)"
```